# What is the basic C# interface scope?

Tags: c#, interface, scope, language-theory

I am having a dispute with another fellow programmer, over the scope of interfaces.

suppose we have the following:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class SomeFoo: IFoo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public SomeFoo(string bar)
    {
        this.Bar = bar;
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        SomeFoo fooClassInstance = new SomeFoo("test");
        IFoo fooInterface = (IFoo)fooClassInstance;

        // do something with fooInterface.
    }
}
```

**So the question is:
1. Is it possible the fooClassInstance to go out of scope before something else releases the fooInterface instance?**

Some argue that the object (fooClassInstance) can go out of scope.

I believe that it cant. Sure, objects may or may not get disposed of by the GC when the GC decides that the object(s) are no longer in scope. However since Interfaces are by design an abstract contract whose members have to be implemented by the object that uses it, than an interface cannot lose its implementation so long as the interface is used. It's not like a whole another object is created of type "interface". The interface is merely a pointer to those abstract members of the implementor.

Can you guys help me resolve this dispute?

Thanks,

```
<bleepzter />
```

Comment: An interface has no implementation, so, yes, the class that *implements* the interface *can* and will go out of scope.  An interface is like a contract - no implementation just a promise of what you *will* implement and therefore nothing to garbage collect.  In your example you are creating a reference to the original object and casting it to an interface - this was the old IUnknown::QueryInterface in COM (though much different now - same concept).

Comment: In your example, both the class and interface instance will go out of scope at the same time.

Comment: No need for casting `fooClassInstance` to `IFoo`. It already *is* `IFoo`.

Comment: @SRM - A *class* is neither in-scope nor out-of-scope.  An *object*, perhaps.  Not trying to be overly nitpicky, but this just that type of question.

Comment: Ok so if i pass the interface to something else, what happens with fooClassInstance? Moreover what happens to the interface's Bar string if it has been passed around, while the fooClassInstance is disposed?

Comment: You don't pass interface. You pass *reference* to an object. Thus if two references point to the same place at memory, you can use either of them. Doesn't matter if one goes out of scope.

Comment: The root of your misunderstanding, bleepzter, is that you think of the two variables as containing two separate objects. They do not. They contain *references*. If you assign one to the other, they will contain references to the *same* object. The type of the variable may be different, but the object they point to is the same.

Comment: The problem with the word "scope" is that everyone uses it to mean whatever they feel like today. "Scope" is very well defined in C#: the *scope* of *something with a name* is the *region of program text in which the thing may be referred to by an unqualified name*.  If you're not talking about program text then the concept you want to be discussing is not *scope* but rather *lifetime*.

Comment: @Justin Good point, I really meant *object* and instead said class, but you are correct.  The *object's* lifetime ends.  See Eric's comment above regarding scope - we should probably start referring it to lifetime because, as Eric pointed out, that is exactly what we are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, what do you mean by "lose its implementation"? That makes no sense. A type implements an interface, it cannot "unimplement" an interface.

As far as your code example goes, the lifetime of the object allocated ends the instant it no longer has any roots (aka, is no longer reachable by the GC). A reference to it is a reference to it, regardless of the type of the reference (i.e. if the reference type is of some derived or parent type, it doesn't matter).

```
ISomething Sample() {
    Something s1 = new Something();
    s2.DoSomething(); // Assuming s is the only reference to s, then it no longer is
                      // rooted after this expression

    Something s2 = new Something();
    ISomething is1 = s2;
    s2 = null;
    is1.DoSomething(); // The reference remains valid and the lifetime of the
                       // object created continues until we release all
                       // remaining references to it.
    return is1;
}
```

Comment: Ok so if i pass the interface to something else, what happens with fooClassInstance? Moreover what happens to the interface's Bar string if it has been passed around, while the fooClassInstance is disposed?

Comment: Provided you maintain a reference to the object, it will continue to remain valid. regardless of the type of the reference, which could be a derived type, a parent type, object, or an implemented interface.

Comment: "... as long as the object is strongly reachable ..." ;-)

Comment: GC Reachability means that the reference is non-weak, as such "strongly" is not needed in that context. Now if weak references had been mentioned/used in his example, then that would be different and clarification would certainly be useful.

Answer (score 3):

While there is definitely some confusion in the terms you are using (I'll let someone else tackle that issue), I *think* I understand what you are saying, and you are basically right.

In particular, it sounds like your coworker believes this is happening:

```
// Now there is this "SomeFoo" object somewhere in memory.
SomeFoo fooClassInstance = new SomeFoo("test");

// Now there is this "IFoo" object somewhere in memory.
IFoo fooInterface = (IFoo)fooClassInstance;

// Let's say down the road somewhere, fooClassInstance is set to null or a different
// object. Your coworker believes that the object it originally pointed to will then
// have no references to it and will thus be eligible for garbage collection?
```

If the above is an accurate representation of what your coworker thinks, then your coworker is wrong and you are right. The `fooInterface` variable contains a reference to the same object that `fooClassInstance` had a reference to. You can easily verify this simply by doing the following:

```
SomeFoo fooClassInstance = new SomeFoo("test");
IFoo fooInterface = (IFoo)fooClassInstance;
bool sameObject = ReferenceEquals(fooClassInstance, fooInterface);
```

If `ReferenceEquals` returns `true`, then the two variables are referencing the same object in memory.

---

If your coworker needs further convincing, try showing him/her something like this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

// This cast is actually not needed; I'm just including it so that it mirrors
// your example code.
IList<int> ilist = (IList<int>)list;

// Now we remove an item from the List<int> object referenced by list.
list.Remove(3);

// Is it in ilist? No--they are the same List<int> object.
Console.WriteLine(ilist.Contains(3));

// How about we remove an item using ilist, now?
ilist.Remove(2);

// Is it in list? Nope--same object.
Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(2));

// And here's one last thing to note: the type of a VARIABLE is not the same
// as the type of the OBJECT it references. ilist may be typed as IList<int>,
// but it points to an object that is truly a List<int>.
Console.WriteLine(ilist.GetType());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are muddling the line between instance an reference. `fooClassInstance` *can* go out of scope (that is, it can no longer be referenced) even if the instance of the object still exists (because `fooInterface` still holds a reference to it).

For example, if you do the following, `fooClassInstance` will not be available after the braces, but fooInterface will.

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    IFoo fooInterface;
    {
        SomeFoo fooClassInstance = new SomeFoo("test");
        fooInterface = (IFoo)fooClassInstance;
    } 

    // do something with fooInterface, but NOT with fooClassInstance
}
```

Comment: Ok so if i pass the interface to something else, what happens with fooClassInstance? Moreover what happens to the interface's Bar string if it has been passed around, while the fooClassInstance is disposed?

Comment: +1 - also note that the garbage collector does not collect references, but instances.  It *uses* the references to find out what instances are still referenced.

Comment: Once `fooClassInstance` goes out of scope (i.e. after the closing brace), it can no longer be used. However, this means that only the variable (label) `fooClassInstance` can no longer be used as a reference to the actual instance of `SomeFoo`. All the while, the instance remains in memory (with whatever the `Bar` string has been set to) because _something_ still has a reference to it (in this case, `fooInterface`).

Comment: @bleepzter - fooClassInstance was *not* disposed (the `Dispose` method was not called explicitly or with a `using` block).  Going out of scope and being disposed are not the same.

Comment: If you play around with VS, you'll see that IntelliSense does a good job of keeping track of scope (which variables are available at a given line of code).

Answer (score 0):

It *sounds* like you are correct, but I feel like we're missing part of the discussion since we don't know what you're doing with the object after you create (and cast) it.

In your example:

```
    SomeFoo fooClassInstance = new SomeFoo("test");
```

At this point, you have one reference to the SomeFoo object referenced by fooClassInstance.

```
    IFoo fooInterface = (IFoo)fooClassInstance;
```

At this point, you have two references to the SomeFoo object (referenced by both fooClassInstance and fooInterface).

So yes, depending on how you use it, fooClassInstance could go out of scope. But there is still a reference to it (fooInterface) so it wouldn't be garbage collected. Also, the fooInterface reference could be cast back to SomeFoo.